# Html.ValidationMessageFor is not displaying the error messages

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following view in my MVC4 application but the problem is the Html.ValidationMessageFor helper is not working. No error message displays next to the TextBox:

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Product", FormMethod.Post, new {id = "productForm"}))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(p => p.ProductName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(p => p.ProductName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor((p => p.ProductName), "*")
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(p => p.InStock)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(p => p.InStock)
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="button" value ="@AppStrings.LabelAdd"/>
}
```

My model is defined as this:

```html
public class Product
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Product name is required.")]
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        
        public bool InStock { get; set; }
    }
```

I have the following in my _Layout.cshtml file that loads the proper jquery validation files

```html
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Html.Script("jquery-ui-1.8.24.js", "jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js")
```

I also have the following in my Web.config file:

```html
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

After all that, the message still does not appear next to the TextBox. However, the client-side validation DOES kick in because the TextBox turns red, but the error message simply does not appear. What am I missing?

Comment: Try just `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.ProductName)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.ProductName, "*")
```

This will display * as validation message, you can place any other text in place of * to display as validation message. If you want to show "*Product name is required.*" as validation message you can just use

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.ProductName)
```

As it will pick up error message from your model.

Comment: I originally thought that the * would get replaced by my validation message. But now I realize doing this just overrides my message.

Comment: @Ray: yeah it overides the model message, however i'm curious to know why you wanted to take star and then replace it by model message as `*` is never displayed? Also can you upvote the answer?

Comment: I thought by putting a star, it would be the default message (signifying that a red star would signal to the user that it is a mandatory field). Then if the user whould leave it blank, the message would appear, but the star kept staying.

Answer (score 1):

try adding below ref to your cshtml file -

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```